# IBM Worklight - cannot change web.xml of the customized .war file prior to deployment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am using IBM Worklight Developer Edition.

I want to change the web.xml of the customized war before getting deployed but I cannot do that because it is auto deployed and the web.xml is auto generated by the Worklight project builder. I tried to add Web-Info folder under {worklightProject}\server folder but it is ignored.

I read that we can control this on Consumer/Enterprise Edition by editing the build ant task. Is there an alternate way for the Developer Version?

Answer (score 2):

The same problem occurs with the Consumer and Enterprise Edition build scripts. The ANT tasks generate the web.xml (in v5.05-5.061) for you and then create the WAR file.

I recommend customizing your build process in Eclipse/Worklight Studio to execute a custom ANT script after the build task is triggered via the Run menu options. This way you can alter the WAR with your own customizations. ANT tasks exist for opening WAR (or any ZIP) archives. After expanded, it's just a matter of performing the customization or including additional files before compressing the changes back into the WAR.

You can find add the custom builders by viewing the project properties -> Builders